# Ignoring previously imported data when importing Excel data to an Outlook appointment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have some code working to import data from Excel when a cell contains the word "Yes". I would like to include code to ignore any entries that have previously been imported when I run the code again.

```
Sub Permits()

    Dim OL As Outlook.Application, Appoint As Outlook.AppointmentItem, ES As Worksheet, _
    r As Long, i As Long, WB As ThisWorkbook

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = WB.Sheets("Permits")
    r = ES.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set OL = New Outlook.Application
For i = 2 To r



    If ES.Cells(i, 10) = "Yes" Then
    Set Appoint = OL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    With Appoint
        .Subject = ES.Cells(i, 3).Value
        .Start = ES.Cells(i, 7) + ES.Cells(i, 8).Value
        .ReminderSet = True
        .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
        .Body = "£" & ES.Cells(i, 6).Value
        .Save
    End With
    End If
Next i
 Set OL = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Use a new column to tag everytime you add an item (i.e. maybe have a column called **'Added'** and then mark it `Yes` once you have set that appointment). You can then either use a filter to only display `non-added` items or check the value in this column to decide if you want to add the appointment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark processed rows with a green colour for example:
(edited as req, it looks for "Yes" in cell 11)

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text 'ignore case sensitivity when comparing strings

Sub Permits()

    Dim OL As Outlook.Application, ES As Worksheet, _
    r As Long, i As Long, WB As ThisWorkbook

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = WB.Sheets("Permits")
    Set OL = New Outlook.Application

    r = ES.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To r
        With ES.Cells(i, 10)
            If .Value = "Yes" And .Offset(0, 1).Value <> "Yes" Then
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = "Yes"
                With OL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
                    .Subject = ES.Cells(i, 3).Value
                    .Start = ES.Cells(i, 7) + ES.Cells(i, 8).Value
                    .ReminderSet = True
                    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                    .Body = "£" & ES.Cells(i, 6).Value
                    .Save
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next i

    Set OL = Nothing
    Set WB = Nothing
    Set ES = Nothing

End Sub
```

You could also create a separate column to mark them etc, edit as needed. Alternatively, you can keep the spreadsheet 'clean' and search for existing reminders with the same data.

Comment: Because of the conditional formatting set up on the worksheet that wouldn't be an option - how could I set it so if (i,10) = "Yes" and (i,11) = "No" then it imports? (assuming that 11 would hold "yes" or "no" for whether it's already imported?

Comment: Apologies, have worked that out - however, is there a way to automatically mark the cells in 11 as "Yes" when the VBA is run?

Comment: No prob, I have edited my response so it now looks for "Yes" in cell 11, and if it's not found it will set a task and enter "Yes". Please mark this answer as correct if it helped :)

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly! You've been a massive help for a complete amateur with VBA